# Wordpress - When visiting a `single post/ single.php` my category menu item link becomes active

Tags: posts, categories, menus, single

I'm new to WordPress. So, I'm not really sure if it's normal behavior or not but this is bothering me. So, I've my main navigation menu consists of `Home | category_1 | Category_2 | Category_3 ...`

The issue is that whenever I click on a post link it loads as expected but the category under which the post is created also becomes active which I don't want. For example, if I click on a post from category_1 it loads with the `single.php` template, and my navigation menu(top navbar) becomes `Home | **category_1(active)** | Category_2 | category_3...`.

So my questions are is it a **normal** behavior in WordPress? And how can I load the single post without making the catgroy link **active**??

Comment: By "active" you mean it gets a class "active", changes its color or both? I suspect this might be coming from the theme itself? Can you check if you get the same result with a default theme?

Comment: @Badan yes, by "active" I meant color and other styling. I'm not sure what did you mean by the default theme. I'm using underscore theme and bootstrap to make my own custom theme

Comment: I found a similar question and helped me finding the solution I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789438/how-to-add-active-class-to-wp-nav-menu-current-menu-item-simple-way